# SVProgressHUD 1.0 not dimming and wrong style

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

I'm using SVProgressHUD 1.0 in my iOS 7 project as follows:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
```

and I'm getting a white HUD with a blue circular arrow (like the 3rd one in the image below--"loading"), and no background dimming.  What I would like is a HUD like the first one in this image:

[image: The first HUD is what I want but I'm getting the third one and no dimming.]

and have the background dim while it's up.  If I switch to version 0.9 I get the dimming, but the HUD is obviously the translucent black type.

How do I get the HUD I'm looking for, with dimming?  (Is it possible to change the style at call time?)

Thanks!

Comment: I did the same thing to you, what I did was install cocoapods and install the stable version by cocoapods and this error is solved,, I attached the file PODFILE: [[[  platform :ios, '7.0' "newline"
pod 'SVProgressHUD' ]]]], I hope it will help.

Comment: That definitely did the trick!  Bizarre.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing to you, what I did was install cocoapods and install the stable version by cocoapods and this error is solved,, I attached the file PODFILE:

```
platform :ios, '7.0' 
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

After installing CocoaPods and re-installing SVProgressHUD via Pod, it worked great...as per comment above.